# module 'http.client' has no attribute 'HTTPSConnection' when I run it in VSCode

Tags: python-3.x, https

I am trying to do the lab exercise of Text Analytics of AI-102-AIEngineer, Microsoft using Python in VSCode. But I get the error

> module 'http.client' has no attribute 'HTTPSConnection'

when I run the code from my VSCode editor. I configured my key and endpoint correctly. The code is here:

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os
import http.client, base64, json, urllib
from urllib import request, parse, error

def main():
    global cog_endpoint
    global cog_key

    try:
        # Get Configuration Settings
        load_dotenv()
        cog_endpoint = os.getenv('COG_SERVICE_ENDPOINT')
        cog_key = os.getenv('COG_SERVICE_KEY')

        # Get user input (until they enter "quit")
        userText =''
        while userText.lower() != 'quit':
            userText = input('Enter some text ("quit" to stop)\n')
            if userText.lower() != 'quit':
                GetLanguage(userText)


    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)

def GetLanguage(text):
    try:
        # Construct the JSON request body (a collection of documents, each with an ID and text)
        jsonBody = {
            "documents":[
                {"id": 1,
                 "text": text}
            ]
        }

        # Let's take a look at the JSON we'll send to the service
        print(json.dumps(jsonBody, indent=2))

        # Make an HTTP request to the REST interface
        uri = cog_endpoint.rstrip('/').replace('https://', '')
        conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection(uri)

        # Add the authentication key to the request header
        headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': cog_key
        }

        # Use the Text Analytics language API
        conn.request("POST", "/text/analytics/v3.0/languages?", str(jsonBody).encode('utf-8'), headers)

        # Send the request
        response = conn.getresponse()
        data = response.read().decode("UTF-8")

        # If the call was successful, get the response
        if response.status == 200:

            # Display the JSON response in full (just so we can see it)
            results = json.loads(data)
            print(json.dumps(results, indent=2))

            # Extract the detected language name for each document
            for document in results["documents"]:
                print("\nLanguage:", document["detectedLanguage"]["name"])

        else:
            # Something went wrong, write the whole response
            print(data)

        conn.close()


    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `/usr/local/lib/python3.8/http/client.py` exists.

In an interractive python console, test:

```py
>>> import http.client
>>> http.client.HTTPConnection('www.python.org')
<http.client.HTTPConnection object at 0x106a9f5f8>

>>> http.client.HTTPSConnection('www.python.org')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'http.client' has no attribute 'HTTPSConnection'
```

Check SSL as well:

```py
>>> import _ssl
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/ishandutta2007/.pyenv/versions/3.5.4/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload/_ssl.cpython-35m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/ishandutta2007/.pyenv/versions/3.5.4/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload/_ssl.cpython-35m-darwin.so
  Reason: image not found
```

It depends on your OS.

For instance, on MacOS, from [this issue](https://github.com/jarun/googler/issues/312#issuecomment-565674814):

> Updating OpenSSL is usually fine, the jump from `libssl.1.0.0.dylib` to `libssl.1.1.dylib` is extremely rare.
> The `dylib` version number 1.0.0 has been the same for years.
>
> However, when it does change and you remove the old one, everything that depends on it will break (Homebrew can do its best making sure its packages are all recompiled, but it can't do anything about your `pyenv` Python installs).
>
> This is not unique to OpenSSL either, just the nature of dynamic linking.
> If one day `libsqlite3.0.dylib` becomes `libsqlite4.0.dylib`, your old Python installs will break too.